# Assuring that all user input is in UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

What do you do to make sure that all user input is to be treated as UTF-8?

Comment: If the input is not UTF8, then `utf8_decode()` will probably fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Anyone can send anything they like.

What you can do is make it obvious to clients that they *should* send UTF-8. Like setting the right Content-Type in your HTML header and of course making sure all content on the page is outputted in utf-8. `htmlentities` has an optional `$encoding` parameter which is useful to know.

If you're using MySQL there's a whole slew more encodings to set, but for PHP/HTML this is about it.